# A team has a $\frac{1}{3}$ probability of winning a game. What is the probability that this team will win the $4^{th}$time in its $10^{th}$ match?

Tags: probability

What's the correct way to solve the problem using $r$ successes in $n$ trials.

Should I calculate $r$ successes in $n$ trials using $r=3$, $n=9$ and then multiply the result with $1/3$?

Or do I just calculate $r$ successes in $n$ trials using $r=4$, $n=10$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first way is correct, 3 successes in 9 trials ensures the 4th success will be on the 10th trial. When you do 4 successes in 10 trials, that allows for possibilities like $W,W,W,W,L,L,L,L,L,L$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.